# YUI datatable not styling

Tags: php, css, yui, yui-datatable

i am using YUI2 to add the plugins to my table.

this is an example:

http://www.tampografica.com/atech/admin/YUIdatatable.html

it is not loading the CSS styling anybody knows why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update

Add the class `yui-skin-sam` to the `div` with an `id` of `markup`.

#### Example

[image: Example]

---

The `link` element is malformed.

```
<link rel=stylesheet type="text/css" href="<link rel=" stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css">
```

...and the HTML parser is using the first `href` attribute it comes across.

Try this...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.9.0/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css">
```

...and then it works!

Comment: sorry i was trying to repairit, look now

Comment: @user Feel free to give me the big green tick then :D